# Creating a view within a stored procedure - unexpected results

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have put together the following create view:

```
CREATE VIEW rm_exporttable 
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        [Item].ID,[Item].ItemLookupCode,
        [ItemClassComponent].Detail1,[ItemClassComponent].Detail2,
        [ItemClassComponent].Detail3,[ItemClass].SubDescription1,
        [ItemClass].SubDescription2,
        [Item].Description,
        ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50), [Item].Notes), '') Notes,
        [Department].Name as DepartmentName,
        [Department].Code DepartmentCode,
        [Category].Name as CategoryName,
        [Category].Code as CategoryCode,
        [Item].Price, [Item].SalePrice, [Item].Cost,
        [Tax].Percentage as Tax, [Item].Quantity, 
        [Item].ReplacementCost,
        ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50), [Alias].Alias), '') Alias,
        [Item].WebItem,  
        CASE 
           WHEN [ItemDynamic].StoreID = 6 
              THEN [ItemDynamic].Price 
              ELSE '' 
        END as GoddardsPrice,
        CASE 
           WHEN [ItemDynamic].StoreID = 5 
              THEN [ItemDynamic].Price 
              ELSE '' 
        END as GoldingPrice,
        [Item].LastUpdated 
    FROM
        Item
    LEFT JOIN
        ItemClassComponent ON [Item].ID = [ItemClassComponent].ItemID
    LEFT JOIN
        ItemClass ON [ItemClassComponent].ItemClassID = [ItemClass].Id
    LEFT JOIN
        Department ON [Department].ID = [Item].DepartmentID
    LEFT JOIN
        Category ON [Category].ID = [Item].CategoryID
    LEFT JOIN
        Tax ON [Tax].ID = [Item].TaxID
    LEFT JOIN
        Alias ON [Alias].ItemId = [Item].ID
    LEFT JOIN
        ItemDynamic ON [Item].Id = [ItemDynamic].ItemID
    LEFT JOIN
        rm_procedurelastran ON [Item].LastUpdated > rm_procedurelastran.date
    WHERE 
        [Item].WebItem = 1
        AND [Item].LastUpdated > [rm_procedurelastran].date
```

This seems to work absolutely fine on its own. Now I'm trying to put it in a simple stored procedure like such:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rmprocedureran1
AS
    exec('Create View rm_exporttable As...')
GO
```

However this doesn't seem to work. The procedure seems to run fine, however when I go to run a simple `select *` statement for the table it returns the error:

> Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax.

It also hasn't managed to create all of the columns.

Can anyone help explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not understanding... *why* are you trying to create a view in a stored procedure...?

Comment: Why are you trying to create a view inside of a procedure in the first place? What happens when you run your proc a second time?

Comment: I'm somewhat limited by a piece of software that runs a procedure then exports a view. So I need the procedure to first generate the view.

Comment: it looks like your view is the problem and not the procedure creating it. You have a column with an invalid cast. Review your view. Is [Item] another view?

Comment: Do you have a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can use to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @mxix          I don't believe it's an issue with the view itself. [Item] is not another view. As mentioned when I create the view outside of a procedure and run a select it works fine. It's only when generating it from a stored procedure does it cause an issue.

Comment: Have you tried comparing the definition of the created view to your working query?  What are the differences?  Without being able to see *exactly* what your proc is doing to generate your `VIEW`, the best anyone here can tell you is: "something is different between your working query and what the proc generated."

Comment: @SQB            I'll try to put one together now and see if that makes the issue clearer.

Comment: In the process of creating an MCVE, I stumbled across the fact that it seems all I needed to do was double up the quotations as part of the exec. The procedure now runs fine. Much simpler that originally feared. Thanks to everyone who responded.

Comment: @Revokez And that is why we ask for an MCVE. By the way, you can self-answer your question to help future users having the same problem.

Comment: @Revokez don't you want also to stop placing empty string to `money` column? There are Zero and Null which are pretty understandable to sql server.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with '' needed to be replaced with '''' (doubling quotations). Correct procedure looks like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE rmprocedureran1
AS
exec('Create View rm_exporttable AS
SELECT DISTINCT [Item].ID,[Item].ItemLookupCode,[ItemClassComponent].Detail1,[ItemClassComponent].Detail2,[ItemClassComponent].Detail3,[ItemClass].SubDescription1,[ItemClass].SubDescription2,[Item].Description,ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50),[Item].Notes),'''') Notes,[Department].Name as DepartmentName,[Department].Code DepartmentCode,[Category].Name as CategoryName,[Category].Code as CategoryCode,[Item].Price,[Item].SalePrice,[Item].Cost,[Tax].Percentage as Tax,[Item].Quantity,[Item].ReplacementCost,ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(50),[Alias].Alias),'''') Alias,[Item].WebItem,CASE WHEN [ItemDynamic].StoreID = 6 THEN [ItemDynamic].Price ELSE '''' END as GoddardsPrice,CASE WHEN [ItemDynamic].StoreID = 5 THEN [ItemDynamic].Price ELSE '''' END as GoldingPrice From Item
Left Join ItemClassComponent
On [Item].ID = [ItemClassComponent].ItemID
Left Join ItemClass
On [ItemClassComponent].ItemClassID = [ItemClass].Id
Left Join Department
On [Department].ID = [Item].DepartmentID
Left Join Category
On [Category].ID = [Item].CategoryID
Left Join Tax
On [Tax].ID = [Item].TaxID
Left Join Alias
On [Alias].ItemId = [Item].ID
Left Join ItemDynamic
on [Item].Id = [ItemDynamic].ItemID
Left Join rm_procedurelastran
On [Item].LastUpdated > rm_procedurelastran.date
Where [Item].WebItem = 1
And [Item].LastUpdated > [rm_procedurelastran].date')
GO
```

Comment: Still definitely **NOT** a good idea to go create a view inside a stored procedure ......